# radius of convergence of a given series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation

How could I find the radius of convergence for the following power series:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{2^{n - 1} x^{2n - 1} }}{{(4n - 3)^2 }}} .
$$
From what I read I need to find: $$
\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sqrt[n]{{a_n }}
$$ and then the field is (-1/Answer,1/Answer)

Note: $a_n$ is the scalar multiplied by $x$.

But that didn't work here. **(I found that R=0.5 which is wrong)**

Comment: You just missed the exponent $2n$ of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing to note about these power series is that they're usually close to a geometric series. These converge iff the ratio is in $(-1,1)$.

Polynomials (in $n$) such as the $(4n-3)^{-2}$ in the denominator don't matter unless the geometric ratio is precisely $-1$ or $1$.

So, first off, take out everything that's not an exponential (you can rigourously show this with the limit you've written down):
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{1}{(4n-3)^2}\left(2x^2\right)^n$$
where the first part is just adjusting, second part is the polynomial (function of $n$ to a constant power), third part is the true exponential (constant to the power $n$). Note the $x^2$ inside the exponential as you have $x^{2n-1}$!

Clearly, it must converge if $2x^2\in(-1,1)$, so $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. The series clearly cannot converge on $|x|>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ as you have an exponential $>1$.

Right at $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ it gets more interesting. At precisely there $x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ what you have is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{(4n-3)^2}$$
and you should know by comparison with say
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
that this converges.

The interval of convergence is $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$, and the radius is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

**PS**: finding $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is fine. What's not is blindly plugging in to say radius of convergence is $(-1/L,1/L)$. You're using the fact that a geometric series converges iff $r<1$, so you need to *solve* the resulting equation $L<1$.

Comment: But an is wrong, it's different than what I wrote

Comment: Corrected, I misread the question

Comment: still it's not right, you get x^(2n-2) but I have x^(2n-1)

Comment: Yeah, editing again. The -1 vs -2 doesn't matter, 2n vs n most definitely does.

Comment: But why I wan't able to say that it converges when |x^(2n-1)|<1? why do I need x^n precisely and nothing else...

Comment: First off, $n$ changes, so the above line isn't written correctly. The point is you're using the fact "a geometric series $\sum r^n$ converges iff $|r|<1$". This result **doesn't** apply (directly) to $\sum r^{2n-1}$, you have to convert it into the correct form.

Comment: You *can* say it converges when $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|2^{n-1}x^{2n-1}|}<1$, which gives the correct answer.

Comment: ok I got that but let us say I have sigma of (-1)^n*3^n*x^2n which I can write as (-1)^n*3^n*(x^2)^n according to what you mentioned it converges when |x|<1 so R=1 but that's wrong

Comment: The problem is not with the limit. The problem is you can't blindly use the result of the limit and just plug in (-1/answer,1/answer). What you should do is solve the equation answer < 1, which in this case gives you $|2x^2|<1$.

Comment: In this new example, you're going to get $|(-1)3x^2|<1$, so $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: But why I need to consider (−1)3? I can't let them stay out while being raised to the power of n, what's the problem with this?

Comment: Think about it - if you ignore all of those other pesky numbers, you're *always* going to get the result $|x|<1$. That's not doing anything useful.

Comment: right, so I can't ignore something to the power of n but can I ignore a normal number like 1/3?

Comment: Yes, the ratio has to consider everything to a power that depends on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy-Hadamard, $r=1/\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n-1]{2^{n-1}/(4n-3)^2}=1/\limsup(2^{(n-1)/(2n-1)}/(4n-3)^{2/(2n-1)}=\limsup 1/\sqrt2/1=1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: the answer written above is different than yours

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Both the ratio test and the root test say

$$|2x^2|<1$$ and this is conclusive.

---

For $2x^2=1$, the denominator is $\sim\dfrac1{16n^2}$ and the series converges (by comparison with the Basel series).